How to build docker image for application written in .NET 8 and use MacOS with M1 for built to linux/amd64
I have following DockerFile and trying to build this image on my MacBook with M1 Max chip:
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/MyProject/MyProject.csproj", "src/MyProject/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/MyProject/MyProject.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/MyProject"
RUN dotnet build "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED=true
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.dll"]

For building the image I tried this command:
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t myproject:latest --load -f src/MyProject/Dockerfile .


I test architecture after build like this:
docker inspect --format '{{.Os}}/{{.Architecture}}' myproject:latest

I got linux/amd64
When I tried to run this image on my server, I got following error and application is not running:
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error

What I tried also:

Clean old local images
Check what architecture is on server with command uname -m and I get x86_64.


Check out Improving multi-platform container support on the .NET Blog. The short answer is to use dotnet restore, dotnet build, and dotnet publish with the -a|--arch <ARCHITECTURE> option and Docker's $TARGETARCH argument.
You can find the latest sample Dockerfile in dotnet-docker on GitHub which I find much clearer, but here's how you might adapt your existing Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG TARGETARCH
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/MyProject/MyProject.csproj", "src/MyProject/"]
RUN dotnet restore -a $TARGETARCH "src/MyProject/MyProject.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/MyProject"
RUN dotnet build "MyProject.csproj" -a $TARGETARCH -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyProject.csproj" -a $TARGETARCH -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED=true
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.dll"]

You can then build your image with the command:
docker build --platform=linux/amd64 -t myproject:latest .


What command I should use to build linux/amd64 image? I tried use TARGETARCH but still same error: standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error
